Appwrite creates new user in Auth but doesnt create it in users database
export const createUser = async (email, password, username) => {
try {
    const newAccount = await account.create(ID.unique(), email, password, username) // try to create new acc

    if (!newAccount) throw Error; // if can't create

    const avatarUrl = avatars.getInitials(username) // if created new account, create an avatar

    await signIn(email, password)

    const newUser = await databases.createDocument(
        databaseId,
        userCollectionId, 
        ID.unique(),
        {
            accountId: newAccount.$id,
            email,
            username,
            avatar: avatarUrl
        }
    )

    return newUser;

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(error)
}

}
This function creates a new user in Auth directory, but it fails to add a user to the database > users folder that i created. I double checked for any errors inside the appwrite folder config but i cant find any... All users are permitted to do anything with the database for now and it's still not working.

I've checked your code.
you said that 'This function creates a new user in Auth directory'
From this, Here is some opinions.
validate databaseId,userCollectionId value and whether field exists.
else of it, check permissions and version.
if you can send me more detail, I can send more.

databaseId and userCollectionId are good, checked it 15 times :D. I gave all users all permissions. If by fields u mean attributes like: email, accountId, username, avatar, yes they all exist in appwrite... I will send the implementation in 2 comments cuz its too big for one...

const { sessionId, checkUser } = useAuth((state) => state);
useEffect(() => {
    checkUser().then((res) => console.log(res))
}, [sessionId])

const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({email: '', password: '', username: ''})

const handleSetCredentials = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setCredentials({...credentials, [id]: value});
  }


const handleSignUp = () => {
createUser(credentials.email, credentials.password, credentials.username).then((res) => {
alert(Succesfully Signed Up!\nEmail: '${res.email}'\nUsername: '${res.username}');
setUser(res.username)
})
}

checked your code. seems no problem. check your router definition and error type.
and then if it's possible, send me a error log.

await signIn(email, password)

When I removed the above line from the code it started working.
